# Can you download a docker image from a repository to a docker container without a running docker daemon?

Tags: docker, security, docker-container, trivy

I have a docker container with Trivy installed.
I have a remote registry with docker images.

and

I would like to download the docker images to the container for scanning

## Challenges

It is hard to run docker within a docker container for pulling the images.
Trivy requires that you have the images locally before it can scan the images, either in a local registry or as a file.

Comment: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2731/downloading-docker-images-from-docker-hub-without-using-docker

Comment: Thanks for the link to the relevant post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two solutions:

1. Download the images with [Skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo)
2. Download the images with the [HTTP API V2](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/)

   - For the API I had a hard time making the authentication work, as it is repository specific, and Scaleways' authentication had unexpected behaviour.